# list-style-image doesn't load in Chrome/Gmail

Tags: css, google-chrome, gmail, html-lists

I have some troubles with CSS in chrome/g-mail. I have a newsletter with custom CSS:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>[newsletters_subject]</title>
    <style type="text/css">.bean li {

    list-style-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/li.png');
}
```

I use the same code in the WP site, works just fine. 
If I send the newsletter the lay-out and li custom image is there but not in G-mail. I don't know why it won't work. Any tips ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good [example of what properties](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/lists/list-style-image/) can be used in email templates. Hope this helps.

Comment: That helps a lot. And if i'm reading that correctly there is nothing I can do about it.